# Update multiple tables with single query, if a condition is met?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

How do I update 2 tables in single UPDATE SET, under some condition ?
If the condition is not met, I'd only update one table..

I'd like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE tab1, tab2 SET
    tab1.value2=7,
    CASE tab1.value1 IS NOT NULL
        WHEN true
        THEN tab2.value1 = tab1.value1 
    END
WHERE tab1.id=1 AND tab2.id = tab1.tab2_fk_id
```

MySQL workbench complains: Syntax Error: Unexpected CASE_SYM

I think I should do this with a TRIGGER - function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanx to Abhik Chakraborty for a brillant solution. It will be surely useful in other context. I have though decided to create a trigger in static_conveyor (~ tab1 in the above example) to achieve equal behavior. I use real tables and column names here instead of generic.. :

```
USE `tca`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `static_conveyor_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `static_conveyor` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.signal != NEW.signal)
    THEN
        IF ((NEW.pallet_id IS NOT NULL) AND (NEW.default_empty IS NOT NULL))
        THEN
            UPDATE pallet SET empty = NEW.default_empty WHERE pallet.id = NEW.pallet_id;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Works nice ..

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can do it,

```
update tab1 ,tab2
join tab2 on tab2.id = tab1.tab2_fk_id
set 
tab1.value2=7,
tab2.value1 = case when tab1.value1 IS NOT NULL then tab1.value1  else tab2.value1 end
where tab1.id=1
```